# Does there exist an elliptic curve $E/\Bbb{Q}$ such that for all quadratic number field $K$, $rank(E/K)=0$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Does there exist an elliptic curve $E/\Bbb{Q}$ such that for all quadratic number field $K$, $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}} \rank(E/K)=0$ ?

Let $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$, $\rank(E/K)=\rank(E/\Bbb{Q})+\rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})$.

So $E/\Bbb{Q}$ need to satisfy $\rank(E/\Bbb{Q})=0$ and $\rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=0$ for all $D: \text{square free integer}$.

Comment: No this is not possible. You can easily show that the root number of $E_D$ is $-1$ for $50\%$ of primes, in which case the rank of $E_D$ should be odd by BSD. There are unconditional results in this direction.